# asp.net mvc3 redirect user after cookie expired

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this problem. When user log in, I create cookie with formsauthanticationticket:

```
var formAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), false, "");
                    var encryptedFormAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(formAuthTicket);
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedFormAuthTicket);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Now. In PreRequestHandlerExecute event i check, if user is authenticated/cookie exists.

```
var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (cookie != null)
        {

            var formAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            var newFormAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(formAuthTicket.Version, formAuthTicket.Name,
                                                                    formAuthTicket.IssueDate,
                                                                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
                                                                    formAuthTicket.IsPersistent,
                                                                    formAuthTicket.UserData,
                                                                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newFormAuthTicket);
            context.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        }
```

But when cookie not exists/expired I want to redirect the user to login page, when he clicks on some link. Any idea?
Thanks

**EDIT**

Because I can't use Authorize attribute. I know about it. I have httpmodule, in assembly, which is referenced in web project. In httpmodule I have Init method, where I initialize PreRequestHandlerExecute() event. In the event I check authentication of user. If I use in "else" something like this -> Response.Redirect(url), occurs cycle redirection, that's wrong. After 10minutes without any request, user clicks some link, he will be redirected to login page -> that's my problem, I can't solve.

Comment: jorge is right.  What you seem to be asking for is default behavior for Forms Authentication.

Comment: Yes I know about this method. But in future, it will be a lot of work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why you just don't use the `[Authorize]` attribute? Added in the sign of your action and if the cookie related with authentication expired will be automatically redirected to the login Page

For example

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Profile()    
{
}
```

And if you need a custom implementation created your custom attribute implement the interface for example

```
public class FooAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     public string fooField{ get; set; }

public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    //Do my stuff
}
```

Then called in your action

```
[FooAuthorizeAttribute]
public ActionResult Profile()    
{
}
```

Comment: Because I can't use Authorize attribute. I know about it. I have httpmodule, in assembly, which is referenced in web project. In httpmodule I have Init method, where I initialize PreRequestHandlerExecute() event. In the event I check authentication of user. If I use in "else" something like this -> Response.Redirect(url), occurs cycle redirection, that's wrong. After 10minutes without any request, user clicks some link, he will be redirected to login page -> that's my problem, I can't solve.